# Copy Data to another sheet and Calculate Totals

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy the names to another tab as well as their costs, and then do the total cost of all similar items.
My logic for the script is to compare each value to the previous copied value and if it is different then the output should be "Total" but if it is the same then the "Name" should be copied. (I basically want to copy the data row by row, value by value, so that I can put certain conditions based on which the copying should happen or not.

The script I have written so far is only for copying the names to the target sheet but even that isn't working out for me. My knowledge is clearly limited, if anyone could help out, that would be great!

This is the [doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D7z5PRDX_fPQfUjjirQznLqXYV5JgNOVHf9TninGKHA/edit#gid=618807860) that I am using, if anyone wants to refer to.

Attached images for those who can't access it:

Source Data:
[image]

How I want the target sheet to look like
[image]

```js
function myFunction() {
  Copy();
}

function Copy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ts = ss.getSheetByName("Total");
 
  for (var n=1;n<10;n++) {
    
    var namesSourceRange = ss.getSheetByName("Breakdown").getRange(1,2,n,1);
    var namesTargetRange = ss.getSheetByName("Total").getRange(1,2,n,1);
    var sourceNames = namesSourceRange.getValues();
    var targetNames = namesTargetRange.getValues();
    
    if (n=1){
    namesTargetRange.setValues(sourceNames);
    }
    else{
    if (sourceNames[n] === targetNames[n-1]){
     namesTargetRange.setValues(sourceNames);
    }
    else {
     namesTargetRange.setValue("Total");
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I think that this question needs more focus. In order to do this, you might reduce the it's scope, in other words, make an specific question about one of the steps of the algorithm that you want to implement. P.S. It's not a good practice to read a single cell on each iteration inside  a loop as this is very slow and there other ways to do this more efficiently. Instead read the all the values that you need with a single statement, for this you have to learn about Arrays in JavasScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

- Sort the source data according to the `Names` column, using [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
- Iterate through the source data, for example, using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Push each row values to another array `destData` which will be used to copy the data to the destination.
- If the row's name is not the same as the next one (that means it's the last row corresponding to this `Name`), or if there's no next one (that is to say, it's the last row in the source data), calculate the `Total` for this name, using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and then push that total to `destData`.
- Use [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to copy `destData` to the destination sheet.

#### Code sample:

```
function Copy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ts = ss.getSheetByName("Totals");
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Breakdown");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(2,2,sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
  sourceData.sort((a,b) => {
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return 1;
    else return -1;
  });
  const destData = [["Names", "Cost"]];
  sourceData.forEach((row, i) => {
    destData.push(row);
    if (sourceData.length === i + 1 || row[0] !== sourceData[i+1][0]) {
      const total = sourceData.filter(rowData => rowData[0] === row[0]).map(row => row[1]).reduce((acc,current) => acc+current);
      destData.push(["Total", total], ["", ""])
    }
  });
  ts.getRange(1,2,destData.length, destData[0].length).setValues(destData);
}
```